# How do I show my wounds to Robbie?

Tags: zelda-breath-of-the-wild

I have a quest that says I can get some more upgrades from Robbie. Now I went to the location and found him, however he wants me to show him my wounds I've gotten 100 years ago.

What exactly does he mean? How do I show him my wounds?

There is a Guardian near the laboratory and I thought it might have something to do with it but I don't wanna get hurt unnecessarily.

Answer (score 127, accepted):

Take your clothes off, my dude.

Comment: Ok if this works I'm gonna feel really stupid... Can't test it currently but yeah It does make sense.

Comment: Zelda games have apparently changed a lot since OOT...

Comment: @mikeTheLiar: Didn't one of the old Zelda games have a scene where your grandmother gives you some "new clothes" (green tunic), but in the NG+ she just gives you nothing?

Comment: @Kevin She gives you clothes that can only be seen by the honest. Apparently you were not one of them.

Comment: If only this were the answer to all life's riddles.

Comment: Also, have Link take his clothes off.

Comment: It took me ages to figures this out too, I thought I had to go find some evidence at the place where Link was injured or something. Then I talked to him again and saw the highlighted 'body' and realised what I needed to do. Really great moment, shows the difference between this game and Skyward Sword, there's hardly a single thing in this game where you are actually told what to do and don't have to figure it out yourself from clues.

Comment: To be specific, you only need to take off your shirt to show Robbie your wounds.

Comment: I really lacked imagination to simply uncloth Link.

Comment: Ah, the solution to so many problems in life.

Comment: @Kevin, the clothes visible only for honest is probably related to folktale "`The Emperor's New Clothes`". I noticed it in `The Elder Scrolls Online`'s book "`Solitude Bedtime Stories`", "`The Jarl's New Robes`" excerpt, too. Related: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Emperor%27s_New_Clothes | https://elderscrolls.fandom.com/wiki/Solitude_Bedtime_Stories