# Is there a limit on how far you can Hollow in Dark Souls II?

Tags: dark-souls-2

In Dark Souls II, whenever you die, your character's Hollowing progresses a little more, reducing your Max Health slightly. However, I am unsure how far the Hollowing can progress, whether to a point of complete Hollowed or a limit on the Health reduction. Does anyone know?

Comment: This will continue until it caps at 50% of maximum HP, unless the player has a sin level of wretch, which it will cap at 95% ([source](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Hollow))

Comment: @somebody Please don't answer in comments, post your answer as an actual answer.

Comment: @0xFF Eh, I don't really think it's right to post an answer if it's just 1. one line and 2. copied 100% from a wiki article (which you can just google up)

Comment: @somebody it completely circumvents the system.  Sure, it might be a simple answer, but people can't vote on it's accuracy this way.  You could lie, and people can't vote it down while potentially misleading readers.

Comment: @JMac Yes. But this kind of question was never intended to be asked on the system - SE isn't really meant for questions you can get the answer from by googling two words

Comment: @somebody don't let the length of an answer deter you from posting one.  Take a look at [this answer](https://gaming.stackexchange.com/a/302392/163757) for example - super sort, but to the point and correct.  Also, just cite the source that you got the information from! ☺

Comment: @somebody There's really no rule against it.  We want to be a good Q and A resource.  This seems like a fairly reasonable question about DS 2.  The answer could have been more complicated, so I don't see why it being simple means the question shouldn't be here.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

According to user @somebody (comments of the question) and to [that source](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Hollow):

> This will continue until it caps at 50% of maximum HP, unless the
>   player has a sin level of wretch, which it will cap at 95%.

As stated by Bart W in the comments, there is a ring that caps the HP loss, according to [the wiki](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Ring_of_Binding):

> [...] stops HP reduction at 80% instead of 50%.

Comment: You might want to add that there's a ring ([link](http://darksouls.wikia.com/wiki/Ring_of_Binding) ) that caps the hp loss a lot earlier (the wiki contradicts itself on different pages as to whether it caps at 25% or 20% loss)

Comment: This should probably be marked as a Community Wiki, as it is [re-posting an answer from the comments](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/117268/365152).

Comment: well, the answer precises "if you're not comfortable rep whoring". which I am comfortable with. I also quoted the source of the answer, so no plagiarism :)